# Function gives a list. I want to multiply that list within another function

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have two functions one that uses the Runge-Kutta method (or midpoint method)  and Euler's method to solve differential equations. However the function it's supposed to solve doesn't let it work.
I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Here's my code

```
    def integrateMidpoint(f, x0, t0, h, N):
        mpxaxis = [0] * (N + 1)
        mpyaxis = [0] * (N + 1)
        mpxaxis[0] = t = t0
        mpyaxis[0] = x = x0
        for x in x0:    
            for i in range(1, N +1):
                k1 = h * f(t, x)
                k2 = h * f(t + 0.5 * h, x + 0.5 * k1)
                mpxaxis[i] = t= t0 + i * h
                x = x + k2
                mpyaxis[i] = [x]
         return mpxaxis, mpyaxis

  def integrateEuler(f,x0,t0,h,N):
    t = t0
    xaxislist = []
    yaxislist = []
    Finalxaxisvalue = N*h # #ofsteps * stepsize
    for x in x0:
        while t <= Finalxaxisvalue:
        xval = t
        yval = x
        t += h
        x += h * f(t,x)
        xaxislist.append(xval)
        yaxislist.append(yval)
    return xaxislist, yaxislist

  def f(t,x):
     return [-x[0]**3 - x[0] + sin(t)] #returns a list
```

I have tried list comprehension where in the Euler function I replaced it with

```
x += [h*i for i in f(t,x)]
```

but I still get the same error in the same line. Originally my program works with the `f(t,x)` function coded like this

```
return -x**3 - x + sin(t)
```

I get a return value of a list, and list of lists. But with this new function with dimensions, I was wondering how would I go about this? List comprehension didn't work. I don't understand why, since I use the values inside the list returned in the function `f(t,x)`.

In the shell I enter:

```
>>>integrateEuler(f, [0.], 0., 1., 10) 
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
Python Shell, prompt 2, line 1
File "redacted.py", line 13, in <module>
multt = [h * i[0] for i in f(t,x)]
File "redacted.py", line 21, in <module>
return [-x[0]**3 - x[0] + sin(t)]
builtins.TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

where `f` is a function, `x0` is the initial condition at time `t0`, `t0` is the initial time, `h` is the step size, and `N` is the number of steps.

Comment: You havent provided `Euler` function code.

Comment: I apologize I was being lazy, but I shortened it to Euler, where it is originally integrateEuler. I'll re-edit it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
 def f(t,x):
     return [-x[0]**3 - x[0] + sin(t)] #returns a list
```

You are trying to use `x` as if it was a list, `x[0]` tries to get the first element of the list. One problem seems to be that everywhere you're calling `f` you are passing a `float` as the second parameter, hence trying to access it as a list raises a `TypeError`, e.g.,

```
# first use in integrateMidpoint
k1 = h * f(t, x)
k2 = h * f(t + 0.5 * h, x + 0.5 * k1)

# second use in integrateEuler
x += h * f(t,x)
```

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you! I realized my mistake. I took out my for loop and now it works! Thanks for the clarification on the error!

Comment: However, how would I multiply it in the integrateMidpoint method specifically k2? I was able to use list comprehension easily in the the Euler method.

Comment: It's hard to tell, the indentation is off in that function. Also I'm not sure what you mean, if you can elaborate with an example maybe I can help.

Comment: So for example in the Euler function, I took out the for loop, and added `x += [[h * i for i in f(t, x)]]` . I was able to return what I wanted, although the initial condition wasn't in a list. '([[0.0, [0.84], etc..). So for the `k2`, how would I go about being able to code it for it to run? Would I have to use multiple list comprehensions, since I can't multiply a float with a list in the second parameter.

Comment: It looks like the values for `k1` and `k2` are independent of `i`, you can move them out of the inner for loop, I think you should restructure and simplify your code before attempting to rewrite using list comprehensions. There are a few things that seem like they could misbehave, e.g. you're modifying the value of `x` while using it as your looping index. I'm not sure that answers your question but I really think you need to reorganize your code so it's easier to understand what you want to do.